# Disable clicks on all day slot

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar 3.2.0 for showing a calendar in my web app. I have turned on all day event slots. However I do not want them to be clickable. I am using select callback for selecting the empty slot, while I am using eventClick for detecting clicks on the event. I want them both to be disabled for all day event. How can I disable click only on all day events and slots?

Here's how I am setting up my calendar

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    weekends: true,
    selectable: true,
    allDaySlot: true,
    timezone: 'local',
    defaultView: 'agendaMonth',
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next',
        height: headerHeight
    },
    overlap: false,
    editable: false,
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    eventSources: events,
    eventLimit: duration,
    defaultEventMinutes: duration,
    select: onSelect,
    eventClick: onEventClick,
    viewRender: onViewRender
});
```

**Update:**
Refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gon2t248/) for more complete example.

Comment: Can you please provide Jsfiddle ?

Comment: @KrnRajput Added the fiddle in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial solution for your problems mentioned above. You can disable click on the all day event by using

```
 var onEventClick = function (event, jsEvent, view){
    if(event.allDay){
        return false;
    }
    alert(event.title);
  }
```

and specifying `allDay: true` in event like

```
{
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
    end: new Date(y, m, d-2),
    allDay: true
},
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0hafpxq/) for your reference.